# SSH connection issue : How to change folder / file permissions in Windows similarly to Linux?

Tags: windows, ssh, permissions, file-permissions, ssh-keys

I have hard times connecting my local PC through SSH to another remote PC. I set the public key on both machines in the authorized_keys folder following this tutorial : `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys` but i get

> permission denied (interactive board, public key)

type of error.
I read that possible solution could be :
`/home/<user> or ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` permissions are too open by OpenSSH standards. You can get rid of this problem by issuing the following commands to change file / folder permission like in Linux :

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

My question how to alter exactly like the mentioned permissions those relating folders in Windows ?

Thanks !
UPDATE : here's the logs server side :

```
Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys error:2
5036 2021-10-18 11:16:06.413 debug1: Could not open authorized keys '__PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Check the server's logs for *why*.

Comment: @vidarlo where to check the log on the server ? which folder and file to look into?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration has information on log path.

Comment: OK thanks but it says `if the user belongs to the administrator group, %programdata%/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys is used instead.` what user the client or the server's users where the folder programdata... mentioned here in my comment is located ?

Comment: @vidarlo check my update for the logs!

Comment: It says invalid user. Does the user exist?

Comment: No sry check my new Update, it is about access the public keys on server side, a problem about permissions, (i solved the user problem !)

Comment: It says `No such file or directory`.

Comment: i know what it says , but why? an ssh connection works but through another software process it returns this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130610/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-patrick-schulz).

Answer (score 2):

While incorrect file permissions can be an issue and they indeed often are, they are not the only cause of login failures.

Rather than trying solutions, please investigate the cause for your problem.
Check for example the [ssh server logging](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Logging-Facilities) for error messages and use those to find an appropriate solution.

If the file permissions on your `$env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\authorized_keys` file  really are the problem: a really quick search found for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/50502015 which details how to set up ssh with public key authentication on a Windows host.

> Setup permissions properly (important!!!):
>
> 1. Run `start .` to open explorer with the current folder (`$env:USERPROFILE\.ssh`);
> 2. Right click `authorized_keys`, go to `Properties -> Security -> Advanced`
> 3. Click "Disable inheritance";
> 4. Choose "Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object" when prompted;
> 5. (really, really important) Remove all permissions on file except for the `SYSTEM` and *yourself*. There must be **exactly two**
>    permission entries on the file. Some guides suggest running the
>    `Repair-AuthorizedKeyPermission $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\authorized_keys`
>
> - this will try to add the `sshd` user to the permission list and it *will* break the authentication, so, don't do that, or at least do not agree on adding the `sshd` user). Both `SYSTEM` and yourself should
>   have full control over the file.

Also see: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Security-protection-of-various-files-in-Win32-OpenSSH

Comment: thanks ! where to check the log on the server ? which folder and file to look into?

Comment: also i put the public key pasted in the file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys   because client is an admin (this is according to the tutorial) but it appears wrong thing to do according to the SO post you referred me to in your answer

Comment: It depends on the version: see https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Logging-Facilities

Answer (score 0):

I come from the future! Bearing gifts!

This is the magic incantation which ye seek!

(from https://webinstall.dev/ssh-authorize/)

## `Repair-AuthorizedKeyPermission`

All of this can be done from a NORMAL, non-elevated PowerShell:

1. Download your public keys from GitHub or wherever your store them

   ```
   curl.exe 'https://github.com/example.keys' | Out-File 'new_authorized_keys'
   ```
2. Create `$HOME\.ssh\authorized_keys` and `${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`

   ```
   New-Item -Type Directory -Force -Path "$HOME\.ssh\"
   New-Item -Type File -Force -Path "$HOME\.ssh\authorized_keys"

   New-Item -Type File -Force -Path "${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys"
   ```
3. Add your downloaded keys to BOTH files

   ```
   type 'new_authorized_keys' | Add-Content -Force -Path "$HOME\.ssh\authorized_keys"
   type 'new_authorized_keys' | Add-Content -Force -Path "${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys"
   ```
4. Explicitly Grant `Administrators` and `SYSTEM` permission to `administrators_authorized_keys`, and yourself to your own keys

   ```
   icacls.exe "${HOME}\.ssh\authorized_keys" /t /grant "${Env:UserName}:(F)"

   icacls.exe "${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /t /grant "Administrators:(F)"
   icacls.exe "${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /t /grant "SYSTEM:(F)"
   ```
5. Remove inherited permissions from BOTH files

   ```
   icacls.exe "$HOME\.ssh\authorized_keys" /inheritance:r

   icacls.exe "${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /inheritance:r
   ```
6. Double check that the permissions are explicit (not inherited):

   ```
   icacls.exe "$HOME\.ssh\authorized_keys" /t
   icacls.exe "${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /t
   ```
7. Remove the downloaded keys

   ```
   Remove-Item -Path 'new_authorized_keys'
   ```

### Double Check

`~/.ssh/` should now have only a single user in its permissions:

```
icacls.exe "$HOME\.ssh\" /t
```

```
C:\Users\alice\.ssh\ Windoze\alice:(F)

C:\Users\alice\.ssh\authorized_keys Windoze\alice:(F)

Successfully processed 2 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Likewise, `${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\` should have very minimal perms:

```
icacls.exe "${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\" /t
```

```
C:\ProgramData\ssh\ NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                    BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                                                  BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)

...
```

## Troubleshooting

### Get a Fresh Start

- Stop ssh-agent & sshd
- Remove or Rename the config files
- Start sshd & ssh-agent

You must be in an Elevated, **Administrator PowerShell** to Stop and Start services.

```
Stop-Service ssh-agent
Stop-Service sshd

Move-Item "$HOME\.ssh" "$HOME\.ssh.old"
Move-Item "$Env:ProgramData\ssh" "$Env:Programdata\ssh.old"

Start-Service sshd
Start-Service ssh-agent
```

### Remove Extra Users

Note: If by some other magic incantation gone awry you still have other non-inherited users, you'll need to remove them manually:

```
icacls.exe "$HOME\.ssh\" /t /remove bob
icacls.exe "${Env:ProgramData}\ssh\" /t /remove bob
```

If someone finds a way to automate the process of listing and removing them (other than direct text processing of the `icacls.exe` output) please let me know.

#### Default Permissions

If you were to `move "$Env:ProgramData\ssh" "$Env:ProgramData\ssh.old"` and *reboot*, this is what you would see:

For reference:

```
icacls.exe "$Env:ProgramData\ssh" /t
```

```
C:\ProgramData\ssh NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
                   BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
                   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
                        BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd.pid NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                            BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                            NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(RX)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                               BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                               NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(RX)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_dsa_key BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_dsa_key.pub BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                                        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_ecdsa_key BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_ed25519_key BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                                        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                                            NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_rsa_key BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)

C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_rsa_key.pub BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                                        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)

Successfully processed 12 files; Failed processing 0 files
```